# Relationship of metaclass's "__call__" and instance's "__init__"?

Tags: python, metaclass

Say I've got a metaclass and a class using it:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args):
        print "Meta: __call__ with", args

class ProductClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self, *args):
        print "ProductClass: __init__ with", args

p = ProductClass(1)
```

Output as follows:

```
Meta: __call__ with (1,)
```

**Question:**

Why isn't `ProductClass.__init__` triggered...just because of `Meta.__call__`?

**UPDATE:**

Now, I add `__new__` for ProductClass:

```
class ProductClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        print "ProductClass: __new__ with", args
        return super(ProductClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        print "ProductClass: __init__ with", args

p = ProductClass(1)
```

Is it `Meta.__call__`'s responsibility to call ProductClass's `__new__` and `__init__`?

Comment: Your `Meta.__call__()` doesn't return anything. It needs to return an instance of the class it's passed as it first argument `cls`. This is usually accomplished by calling a method of the same name in its parent (aka base) class. That can be done by hardcoding it, i.e `return type.__call__(, *args)`, or by using  `return super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args)`.

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference in OOP between extending a method and overriding it, what you just did in your metaclass `Meta` is called overriding because you defined your `__call__` method and you didn't call the parent `__call__`. to have the behavior that you want you have to extend `__call__` method by calling the parent method:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args):
        print "Meta: __call__ with", args
        return super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - it's up to `Meta.__call__` to call `ProductClass.__init__` (or not, as the case may be).

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

> for example defining a custom `__call__()` method in the metaclass
>   allows custom behavior when the class is called, e.g. not always
>   creating a new instance.

That page also mentions a scenario where the metaclass's `__call__` may return an instance of a different class (i.e. not `ProductClass` in your example). In this scenario it would clearly be inappropriate to call `ProductClass.__init__` automatically.

Comment: what if I got a "__new__" in ProductClass? Will Meta's "__call__" call ProductClass's "__new__" and "__init__"? See my UPDATE.

Comment: And apparently, Meta's "__call__" is called first before ProductClass's "__new__".

Comment: The problem is that `Meta.__call__` is required to call `ProductClass.__new__` and `ProductClass.__init__`. Normally, `type.__call__` does this for you, but when you define `Meta.__call__` you _override_ that behaviour, meaning it's not executed unless you do so. So, you're either required to call `__new__` and `__init__` yourself, or make a call to something like `type.__call__(cls, *args)`.